# Why wont my molecular script initiate velocity?

Tags: physics

I am making a molecular script, and I added a velocity object aligned x of -20. When I Bake it, it shows this:
[image: Gif of viewport render]

How do I make the velocity slowly decrease until it hits something instead of having that velocity, then stopping after a few seconds.

Here is the blend file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/cd46a585ccf04e539fbc807fb1499001

I don't understand why it is stopping. Gravity also seems to be affected, they are falling too slow..

Comment: Please provide blend file

Comment: Question updated with blend file.

Comment: sorry, but i will not ask for access to your file...

Comment: @CruzeClevenger Please upload your blend file at blend-exchange.com or pasteall.org

Comment: @Chris Updated with Pasteall File.